# how do I understand what's causing app to crash from crash log?

Tags: iphone, ipad, sdk, nstimer, crash-log

This is my crash log:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xd1e5501b
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x36943c98 objc_msgSend + 16
1   Bedside Peek                    0x00033516 0x30000 + 13590
2   Foundation                      0x345487c6 __NSFireTimer + 130
3   CoreFoundation                  0x34429a40 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 8
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3442bec4 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 844
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3442c83e __CFRunLoopRun + 1082
6   CoreFoundation                  0x343bcebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
7   CoreFoundation                  0x343bcdc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
8   GraphicsServices                0x33b22418 GSEventRunModal + 108
9   GraphicsServices                0x33b224c4 GSEventRun + 56
10  UIKit                           0x349f4d62 -[UIApplication _run] + 398
11  UIKit                           0x349f2800 UIApplicationMain + 664
12  Bedside Peek                    0x000316cc 0x30000 + 5836
13  Bedside Peek                    0x00031680 0x30000 + 5760

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x344b2fbc kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x36acded4 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 744
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x36acef3a _dispatch_queue_invoke + 70
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x36ace4ec _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 228
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35ab758a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35ab7bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x344afc00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x344af758 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3442a2b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3442c562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x343bcebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x343bcdc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                         0x313e927e RunWebThread(void*) + 382
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35ab630a _pthread_start + 242
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35ab7bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x344afc00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x344af758 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3442a2b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3442c562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x343bcebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x343bcdc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   Foundation                      0x344e27f6 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 206
7   Foundation                      0x344d5382 -[NSThread main] + 38
8   Foundation                      0x345475c6 __NSThread__main__ + 966
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35ab630a _pthread_start + 242
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x35ab7bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x344b1c60 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x3442f8f2 __CFSocketManager + 582
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35ab630a _pthread_start + 242
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35ab7bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x1e550430    r1: 0x34cb7a68      r2: 0x1e550430      r3: 0x34cb7a68
    r4: 0xd1e55013    r5: 0x00000001      r6: 0x1e527cd0      r7: 0x2fe2da60
    r8: 0x1e527d90    r9: 0x2fe2da0c     r10: 0x1f057470     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x000334f1    sp: 0x2fe2d9e4      lr: 0x0003351d      pc: 0x36943c98
  cpsr: 0x20000030

Binary Images:
   0x30000 -    0x38fff +Bedside Peek armv7  <1b5a166e5c533073bbb7071982e922c4> /var/mobile/Applications/84F9A372-F6CC-43AD-886F-8656C69AB9E1/Bedside Peek.app/Bedside Peek
 0x1ef3000 -  0x1ef7fff  AccessibilitySettingsLoader armv7  <977d3eb9b0a4389e85e0e8eb64806759> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/AccessibilitySettingsLoader.bundle/AccessibilitySettingsLoader
0x2fe2f000 - 0x2fe54fff  dyld armv7  <4d3190188cbf32a8a73f32a8b5bb7adf> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30cf4000 - 0x30cfdfff  CoreVideo armv7  <ea847e6dba2d36b1826b255c73b39539> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x30e32000 - 0x30e37fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <f5ccc8234aea3ebd9a88bd37f0fa23ae> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x30e38000 - 0x30f59fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <65f6c8701b563542820a26b0dfc4f6a4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x30f5b000 - 0x30f5bfff  Accelerate armv7  <7d5ad465049136afaa1f0d89aac600bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x30f5c000 - 0x30f8ffff  StoreServices armv7  <d526715648f435c3aac4c42953e76d20> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x311de000 - 0x311e9fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <ac706bee36593dc683fd5a96a389d72e> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x311ea000 - 0x31230fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <af7d1e770e5a3ffd8834a57fb5d40557> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x31281000 - 0x312c4fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <f790c26852cb3cf298abe56bc9a3940b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x312c5000 - 0x312d5fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <66d9047da79a31daa887e6d84c42ecb2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x312d6000 - 0x31395fff  CFNetwork armv7  <b09e0d53de9f3bc8bde494780f3cdd4f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x31396000 - 0x31397fff  DataMigration armv7  <42e9e87a4e0735c3837e27d4f2adcf55> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x313a6000 - 0x313aafff  libcache.dylib armv7  <362fdd2de66f3e189b5d139c9669a9e3> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x313ab000 - 0x313e2fff  Security armv7  <6599f42a910b3b31a0e1d98c883d61cb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x313e3000 - 0x319eefff  WebCore armv7  <07941e59d0a33f94802c16c76238fddf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x319ef000 - 0x31b3bfff  MediaToolbox armv7  <482b13059e8a329fa5d832baede25103> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x33821000 - 0x33826fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <e32cf2d48a1f3060b372ca7623e4a12b> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x33827000 - 0x3383cfff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <e92cfbb83f7b330db19181e797bb3f7b> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x3383d000 - 0x33941fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <61a94142e2d23dafa2964190dd46e9e3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x33950000 - 0x339affff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <0b36b2272aa33a8c9aa22d99c89d7189> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x339c2000 - 0x33b16fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <6619c8c13f8d328e923e797fa8d0df23> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x33b17000 - 0x33b1dfff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <f9277ee9b85b3722975ad319a323aca0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x33b1e000 - 0x33b2afff  GraphicsServices armv7  <ff78a9636e933f0dbd222f8d26209788> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x33b2b000 - 0x33b30fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <f019bc513a6a37f4a79555b3ffb2a777> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x33c0b000 - 0x33c55fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <e98c3fd72ba43d02aac24b08f7219eb7> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x33d58000 - 0x33dc7fff  ProofReader armv7  <6d843c6aecdd37ae84baa40af8ad7e65> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x33de7000 - 0x33de8fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <ccc041df3de73eafb7a59e74cdb1702b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x33dfe000 - 0x33dfefff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <f47c01d627853b328e088b3fdd08e87d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x33e16000 - 0x33e5cfff  CoreLocation armv7  <249b8af3dc503d11bf3711f0407c66d8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x33e7f000 - 0x33f14fff  ImageIO armv7  <d520e3241d1130e8ac1375ee0f2c1095> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x33f25000 - 0x33f3bfff  EAP8021X armv7  <9fefc0ada30435fbb3b51818c74f6cb8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x34035000 - 0x34064fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <1d73b8a159363f96bb9c039655c5eae6> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x3421a000 - 0x34334fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <bada0c2725bb31a483d5adf9aaf1f8df> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x3436b000 - 0x3436efff  ApplePushService armv7  <015c68c15621348db9f6a012499170e1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x34381000 - 0x34381fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <42d8aa2a31843a6e8bfff745644a7ba5> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x343b4000 - 0x34499fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <a8444f997111304c9571b3ff974b769c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x344a0000 - 0x344b7fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <c4ebe7eb2e6c3a2d9bd3620a4d6dbc0e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x344b8000 - 0x345d7fff  Foundation armv7  <09ff368178c5321c9715b9c8d491d53f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x345d8000 - 0x345e2fff  AccountSettings armv7  <d083fb384dc7311eb6766b9b2d2dd9c8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x3463e000 - 0x34640fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <d55f1553d14831a2a5435ae27ef75ef4> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x34648000 - 0x34650fff  MobileBluetooth armv7  <63f11756c4aa3262b2317ff3b8e2a977> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x34751000 - 0x34752fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <7dd4acfe150831e0ae82296587e67e7f> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x34775000 - 0x3477bfff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <14c89b7346433c1f8675f454531f6ca3> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x34964000 - 0x3496bfff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <ab9777b39e8e3026ad64dc90323cad7e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x3496c000 - 0x34985fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <4825c3e392983aba947eca06555e4480> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x34988000 - 0x349c5fff  CoreText armv7  <fb6a72faec2330c4b2cd33c2e9c59588> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x349c6000 - 0x34d53fff  UIKit armv7  <c271b78464d93cb7bf28c6e49df293ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x34ed3000 - 0x34edcfff  MobileWiFi armv7  <03d98d5cf6383695aa7d8a88da52f410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x34ef3000 - 0x34efafff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <0a082e1d475432959ba93aa3dbf7fb31> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x34efd000 - 0x34efffff  MobileInstallation armv7  <94b6d6c5d9883175af26764567528127> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x34f3a000 - 0x34f40fff  IAP armv7  <c0f4c99a1b493e489948f231ad9238e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x34f43000 - 0x34f55fff  VoiceServices armv7  <d219dd8a59c93390b3461a015e28b29c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VoiceServices.framework/VoiceServices
0x34f57000 - 0x34f76fff  Bom armv7  <b178e3efb4d733c694bd5a55e57a314f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x3514d000 - 0x3514efff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <0fa08e1bb47a3d179072a933d1726597> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x35161000 - 0x35196fff  AddressBook armv7  <3f2071a77bc134cd82065eef90d4082f> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x351c9000 - 0x35201fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <416c77100b453e3f838831c4c857f8c7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x35202000 - 0x3520cfff  ExternalAccessory armv7  <eebb4bdbbefb37419b884ffa011e1dc5> /System/Library/Frameworks/ExternalAccessory.framework/ExternalAccessory
0x352f6000 - 0x352f9fff  IOSurface armv7  <ad50e71624583d06b891344d832f9b08> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x352fa000 - 0x352fcfff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <a2631ac302f4310dae8367939e16b7c2> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x35341000 - 0x353eafff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <5538d3f2c7d83b88b06168488fe6326b> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x3547f000 - 0x35488fff  ITSync armv7  <ba8b48d061903e4096774344448776d0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x35489000 - 0x35495fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <c68262667ac8397a949ce4e92dfec7db> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x35594000 - 0x35681fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <f4146ce07e3031ea8a81fa5516fd77d0> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x35a83000 - 0x35b04fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <17ee3fe220c23b1f898d21ba25b2bcac> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x35b15000 - 0x35b19fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <a0772a32cd8b3b9194bb0c29807c1c5b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x35b1a000 - 0x35b5cfff  CoreAudio armv7  <c972fd5f8e89333ca680b9a33587f896> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x35b5d000 - 0x35c03fff  Celestial armv7  <407badafc6403692bf099d542d28bf7f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x35d11000 - 0x35d16fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <8c35c090bc373cb181fc26b961b8dba5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x35d18000 - 0x35d35fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <48016be86e3f3cd9aeee1c6590e1ac6f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x35d7d000 - 0x35e2efff  WebKit armv7  <eb9a0d69c64b3127b2bffd71641add3b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x35e2f000 - 0x36142fff  GeoServices armv7  <88616f3deada3bb495fc15e3ba58dc83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x36143000 - 0x3616cfff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <57fef84bdc17301d8bf53ba0fb967fe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x3616d000 - 0x3616efff  CoreSurface armv7  <7b83cd757da73e6e826693c29296d3fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x3616f000 - 0x3617cfff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <0a1e2bb78d5138419ecad8ba0fe42fdd> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x3617d000 - 0x36239fff  MapKit armv7  <806f9ca7eb593d1998587441ce87a396> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x3624a000 - 0x3628afff  CoreMedia armv7  <8e0570582ba535bfa74f1f00eef64376> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x362a1000 - 0x362f2fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <8a41cc6a6d9332308bc415d27577fd24> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3643e000 - 0x36472fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <570c63dc3a273a5a8c9072fd5567f5c1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x365d5000 - 0x368c2fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <b855d60dac01310495453bddfd004f0d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x368ca000 - 0x368cafff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <21415179ffa03f949fa8cc851c6c31c7> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x368cb000 - 0x3690afff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <64cf947dd8423eeeb677f81dd3eb2d9d> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x36941000 - 0x36a05fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <a89ef30f6d663254babb6329ce02ca3d> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x36a06000 - 0x36a09fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <fc834fd33a18341ea7506587ad895703> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x36a26000 - 0x36a39fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <529ea6e3a87230ce9f6cf3285c22429c> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x36a42000 - 0x36a54fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <659ea9d5b13d3fefb37acff09016a69c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x36a58000 - 0x36a5cfff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e1cbfe599c96369ca4bdb0dd99d3cd9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x36ac2000 - 0x36ac4fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <683f321680763e519d61541170ba2133> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x36acd000 - 0x36adafff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9a0511ad5ebc3db898f1f49ed1a73d34> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x36aee000 - 0x36af3fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9d7198e91de9386a9e5ea43608a66a57> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x36b27000 - 0x36bd6fff  QuartzCore armv7  <ef9632c9781f3101916b65e9faae1579> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x36bd7000 - 0x36bdafff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <53908d448e9e32418652a4afee5bc578> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x36c9d000 - 0x36cd0fff  AppSupport armv7  <0217468bd9f839229a47910b7816b3d5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x36cd1000 - 0x36cd8fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <55f29184efcc3046bb833dd72a4487e1> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x36d66000 - 0x36deafff  AVFoundation armv7  <eeaf5f4f822436a5bd1655f536e69879> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x36deb000 - 0x36e39fff  GMM armv7  <049361f664eb3f30b0d25cd56ffc1f0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x36e3a000 - 0x36e3bfff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <3e0b7d6754cd33669c0680525f03ede1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x36e80000 - 0x36ed5fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <0221caba81a235c5a896a835e2aac047> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x36ee3000 - 0x36f31fff  CoreMotion armv7  <5e6b884d36d93789b40b7f3876130417> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x36f3e000 - 0x36f40fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <9e7efa009730322f84bbc5d8bf1ded94> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x36f41000 - 0x36f4ffff  OpenGLES armv7  <5a76beaeaa013f0cbf16e5cb154598ab> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x36f50000 - 0x36f88fff  IOKit armv7  <80ae313ad69d3363935c88e51a11862d> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x36f8d000 - 0x36fadfff  PrintKit armv7  <e5a01ca9083a36afacc08611a398e2ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x3717c000 - 0x371b8fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <9d97699e44ee3651ba4ac37e5adec35b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x372f9000 - 0x37396fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <e354aeb3d96e30338e90cc3638ffe81b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x37397000 - 0x37397fff  vecLib armv7  <0c60cd0a60f43d2791d36cb357d30e3c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
```

I have run NSZombies, tested on multiple iPads, and tried everything I can think of. The app, which is an alarm clock style app, works perfectly for 3-4 hours, then mysteriously crashes. Anyone have any ideas why?

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS is always pain in the ass. The log says it crached in Thread 0. I suggest to check what the __NSFireTimer is going to do there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not always easy to see what has happened in these crash reports. Often it is only showing unreadable addresses instead of meaningful method names. In order to fix this you have to symbolize the crash report. I suggest do a search on google in order to see how to do that.

I can also recommend using the free service at www.testflightapp.com for distribution. They have also released an SDK that you can implement in your application during development/debugging. It gathers crash reports from all the testers and present it in a nice web interface. You can also easily upload the .dsym file needed for symbolizing the logs in this interface.